# How to get ActionResult from ActionExecutingContext?

Tags: .net, redirect, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter, actionresult

I'm looking to get the action that caused [`OnActionExecuting()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuting%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) in an overridden [`ActionFilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). The idea is to save this in the session so the user can be redirected to their intended page after entering an interim "Change Password" page.

My current attempt is:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)
{
    // ...
    ActionResult originatingActionResult = new RedirectToRouteResult(
        new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            { "controller", actionExecutingContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName },
            { "action", actionExecutingContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName }
        });
    // ...
```

But this seems rather complex for what is being done - is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it could be simplified as:

```
ActionResult originatingActionResult = new RedirectToRouteResult(
        new RouteValueDictionary(filterContext.RouteData.Values));
```

However...

The project uses T4MVC and `RedirectToAction` couldn't be used as it is overridden on the controller and expects `GetT4MVCResult()` to be present on the `ActionResult`.

So I ended up doing it like this instead:

```
RouteValueDictionary originatingRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(
    actionExecutingContext.RouteData.Values);

// ... followed by ...

return this.RedirectToRoute(routeValues);
```